# How can I optimize this code in python? For solving stochastic differential equations

Tags: python, numpy

I am developing a code that uses a method called Platen to solve stochastic differential equations. Then I must solve that stochastic differential equation many times (on the order of 10,000 times) to average all the results. My code is:

```
import numpy as np 
import random 
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def integrador2(y,t,h):  #this is the integrator of the function that solves the SDE
    m = 6.6551079E-26    #parameters
    gamma=0.05
    T = 5E-3
    k_b = 1.3806488E-23
    b=np.sqrt(2*m*gamma*T*k_b)
    c=np.sqrt(h)
    for i in range(len(t)):
        dW=c*random.gauss(0,1)  
        A=np.array([y[i,-1]/m,-gamma*y[i,-1]]) #this is the platen method that is applied at              
        B_dW=np.array([0,b*dW])                #each time step
        z=y[i]+A*h+B_dW                 
        Az=np.array([z[-1]/m,-gamma*z[-1]])
        y[i+1]=y[i]+1/2*(Az+A)*h+B_dW
    return y

def media(args):   #args is a tuple with the parameters 
    y = args[0]
    t = args[1]
    k = args[2]
    x=0
    p=0
    for n in range(k): #k=number of trajectories          
        y=integrador2(y,t,h)                           
        x=(1./(n+1))*(n*x+y[:,0]) #I do the average like this so as not to have to save all the 
        p=(1./(n+1))*(n*p+y[:,1]) #solutions in memory
    return x,p
```

The variables y, t and h are:

```
y0 = np.array([initial position, initial moment])   #initial conditions
t = np.linspace(initial time, final time, number of time intervals)  #time array
y = np.zeros((len(t)+1,len(y0)))   #array of positions and moments
y[0,:]=np.array(y0) #I keep the initial condition
h = (final time-initial time)/(number of time intervals)  #time increment
```

I need to be able to run the program for a number of time intervals of 10 ** 7 and solve it 10 ** 4 times (k = 10 ** 4).
I feel that I have already reached a dead end because I already accelerate the function that calculates the result with Numba and then (although I do not put it here) I parallelize the "media" function to work with the four cores that my computer has. Even doing all this, my program takes an hour and a half to execute for 10 ** 6 time intervals and k = 10 ** 4, I have not had the courage to execute it for 10 ** 7 time intervals because my intuition tells me that it would take more than 10 hours.
I would really appreciate if someone could advise me to make some parts of the code faster.

Finally, I apologize if I have not expressed myself completely correctly in any part of the question, I am a physicist, not a computer scientist and my English is far from perfect.

Comment: This may get more attention on Code Review.  But check for relevant tags and requirements (full running code etc).  I usually don't recommend CR, but you seem to have used the speedups most recommended on SO, such as `numba`.  So it may come down to coding details and organization, the kind of thing that CR answers seem to focus on.  SO is better for debugging and focused questions.

Comment: Can you please post [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can save about 75% of compute time by simplifying the math in the loop:

```
def integrador2(y,t,h):  #this is the integrator of the function that solves the SDE
    m = 6.6551079E-26    #parameters
    gamma=0.05
    T = 5E-3
    k_b = 1.3806488E-23
    b=np.sqrt(2*m*gamma*T*k_b)
    c=np.sqrt(h)

    h = h * 1.
    coeff0 = h/m - gamma*h**2/(2.*m)
    coeff1 = (1. - gamma*h + gamma**2*h**2/2.)
    coeffd = c*b*(1. - gamma*h/2.)
    
    for i in range(len(t)):
        dW=np.random.normal()
        
        # Method 2
        y[i+1] = np.array([y[i][0] + y[i][1]*coeff0, y[i][1]*coeff1 + dW*coeffd])
    return y
```

Here's a method using filters with scipy, which I don't think is compatible with Numba, but is slightly faster than the solution above:

```
from scipy import signal

# @numba.jit(nopython=True)
def integrador2(y,t,h):  #this is the integrator of the function that solves the SDE
    m = 6.6551079E-26    #parameters
    gamma=0.05
    T = 5E-3
    k_b = 1.3806488E-23
    b=np.sqrt(2*m*gamma*T*k_b)
    c=np.sqrt(h)

    h = h * 1.
    coeff0a = 1.
    coeff0b = h/m - gamma*h**2/(2.*m)
    coeff1 = (1. - gamma*h + gamma**2*h**2/2.)
    coeffd = c*b*(1. - gamma*h/2.)
    
    noise = np.zeros(y.shape[0])
    noise[1:] = np.random.normal(0.,coeffd*1.,y.shape[0]-1)
    noise[0] = y[0,1]
    a = [1, -coeff1]
    b = [1]
    y[1:,1] = signal.lfilter(b,a,noise)[1:]
    a = [1, -coeff0a]
    b = [coeff0b]
    y[1:,0] = signal.lfilter(b,a,y[:,1])[1:]
    
    return y
```